# Pass Additional Parameters to Prechat?

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, pre-chat, pre-chat-api

So the code to include the prechat component looks something like below:

```
<div class="prechat">
    <img id="liveagent_button_online_573000000000000"
        onclick="liveagent.startChat('573000000000000')"
        src="https://myinstance.force.com/resource/.../LiveChatImage" />
    <div id="liveagent_button_offline_573000000000000">
        <!-- Offline Chat Content -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
        window._laq.push(function(){
            liveagent.showWhenOnline('573000000000000', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_573000000000000'));
            liveagent.showWhenOffline('573000000000000', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_573000000000000'));
        });
    </script>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c1cs-phx.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/43.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://mypath.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572000000000000', '00D000000000000');
</script>
```

The only call that jumps out at me as promising is `liveagent.startChat('573000000000000')`. However, when I look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_launching_chat_request_API_startChat.htm), this method does not have any parameters which seem of use. Nor does the [`startChatWithWindow`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_launching_chat_request_API_startChatWithWindow.htm) method.

**Is there any way to pass parameters into the created window for Live Agent Prechat?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use post messaging for this requirement. Minimum viable product:

**Host Site**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    liveagent.init(...);
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        if (event.origin !== "https://myinstance.force.com") { return; }
        if (event.data === "livechatinit") {
            event.source.postMessage({
                "title": "I changed the title!"
            }, "*");
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Prechat Page**

```
(function(w) {
    const endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
    const originWhitelist = [
        "https://www.example.com"
    ];
    w.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById("prechatForm").setAttribute(
            "action", decodeURIComponent(
                endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1].replace("javascript:", "")
            )
        );
        w.opener.postMessage("livechatinit", "*");
        w.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if (originWhitelist.indexOf(event.origin) < 0) { return; }
            if (event.data) {
                if (event.data.title) {
                    document.title = event.data.title;
                }
            }
        });
    }, false);
})(window);
```